# systemd timer - how to get history of when timer triggered

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

```
systemctl status mytimer.timer
```

Tells me since when it is active and when the next trigger is due. How can I get a list of when the timer triggered in the past?

Answer (score 9):

List timers, and show journal for the journal/log unit history:

```
systemctl list-timers
# replace motd-news with mytimer
journalctl -u motd-news.timer
```

Output:

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2018-11-02 13:17:39 CDT, end at Sat 2018-11-03 11:20:59 CDT. --
Nov 02 13:17:52 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
Nov 02 18:45:46 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
-- Reboot --
Nov 02 18:46:47 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
-- Reboot --
Nov 03 07:57:27 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
```

Some other helpful flags:

- `--since` starting time to current
- `--until` used with since will get a time range
- `--reverse` show newest first
- `--grep` grep the message for a pattern

The other flags of interest for getting just the time would be using the `--output` flag, along with the `--output-field` flag, f

> -o, --output=
>          Controls the formatting of the journal entries that are shown. Takes one of the following options:
>
> ```
>    short
>        is the default and generates an output that is mostly identical to the formatting of classic syslog files, showing one line
>        per journal entry.
>
>    short-full
>        is very similar, but shows timestamps in the format the --since= and --until= options accept. Unlike the timestamp information shown in short output mode this mode
>        includes weekday, year and timezone information in the output, and is locale-independent.
>
>    short-iso
>        is very similar, but shows ISO 8601 wallclock timestamps.
>
>    short-iso-precise
>        as for short-iso but includes full microsecond precision.
>
>    short-precise
>        is very similar, but shows classic syslog timestamps with full microsecond precision.
>
>    short-monotonic
>        is very similar, but shows monotonic timestamps instead of wallclock timestamps.
>
>    short-unix
>        is very similar, but shows seconds passed since January 1st 1970 UTC instead of wallclock timestamps ("UNIX time"). The time is
>        shown with microsecond accuracy.
>
>    verbose
>        shows the full-structured entry items with all fields.
>
>    export
>        serializes the journal into a binary (but mostly text-based) stream suitable for backups and network transfer (see
>        Journal Export Format[1] for more information). To
>        import the binary stream back into native journald format use systemd-journal-remote(8).
>
>    json
>        formats entries as JSON data structures, one per line (see Journal JSON Format[2] for more information).
>
>    json-pretty
>        formats entries as JSON data structures, but formats them in multiple lines in order to make them more readable by humans.
>
>    json-sse
>        formats entries as JSON data structures, but wraps them in a format suitable for Server-Sent Events[3].
>
>
>   cat
>        generates a very terse output, only showing the actual message of each journal entry with no metadata, not even a timestamp.
> ```
>
> --output-fields=
>
> ```
>        A comma separated list of the fields which should be included in the output. This only has an effect for the output modes which
>        would normally show all fields (verbose,
>        export, json, json-pretty, and json-sse). The "__CURSOR", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP", and "_BOOT_ID" fields
>        are always printed.
> ```

Comment: This sort of works, though it is pretty verbose in my case. The service logs a lot of things, so there is a fair bit of scrolling and skimming required. I was hoping to get a simple list of datetimes, one for each trigger.... Is that available?

Comment: @pandita it is possible using some extra command flags. I've added the info. hope it helps.

Comment: This is useful. I guess I can write a little filter with bash to show me the trigger times. Upvote but I leave it open for a little bit in case someone else chimes in. Thanks!

Comment: @pandita ... it's been almost five years, perhaps it's time to accept and give jmunsch 15 reps (that still cannot be cashed in on a latte :-/)?